# NHibernate query cache not working after update to the database

Tags: nhibernate, caching, fluent-nhibernate

I have enabled 2nd level cache in FluentNHibernate:

```
Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
            .ConnectionString(connectionString)
            .Cache(c => c.ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>().UseQueryCache())
            )
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PersonMap>());
```

My mapping is as follows:

```
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
```

When I call Persons from my repository, I run:

```
    var query = session.GetSession().CreateCriteria<Person>("p")
        .Add(Expression.Eq("p.Org.Id", orgRep.GetOrg().Id));
    query.SetCacheable(true);
    return query.List<Person>().AsQueryable<Person>();
```

When I start the application everything (including cache) works fine. My first query will hit the database, but following ones don't. Problem arises when I save the Person. Person is saved like:

```
public virtual void Save(Person p)
{
  if (p.Id > 0 && session.GetSession().Get<Person>(p.Id).Org != orgRep.GetOrg())
            throw new SecurityException("Organization mismatch");
  session.GetSession().Merge(p);
  session.GetSession().Flush();
}
```

Saving works but after that the cache doesn't. Queries will always hit the database. Looking through nhibernate log says that:

```
 DEBUG - Checking query spaces for up-to-dateness [[Person]]
 DEBUG - Fetching object 'NHibernate-Cache:UpdateTimestampsCache:[Person]@1639794674' from the cache.
 DEBUG - cached query results were not up to date for: sql: SELECT this_.Id as Id0_0_, this_.Name as Name0_0_, this_.Org_id as Org5_0_0_ FROM [Person] this_ WHERE this_.Org_id = ?; parameters: ['1']; first row: 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3339 this bug post looks something similar although it is in the session level. If I reset my SessionFactory after the Flush, the cache starts working again. But resetting the SessionFactory resets all 2nd level caches with it. Can it be that the timestamp is somehow incorrect when doing the same query in the same session factory after save?

Comment: Nobody has any suggestions what might go wrong here?

Comment: A [more detailed answer](/a/14301438/1178314) is now available on a near dup question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instantiating an explicit transaction within a session using block. This article looks relevant:- http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions

Comment: Good that you answered this. Actually I think we got it eventually to work by using transactions. Using transactions is crucial for second level cache.