# NHibernate query cache not used

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NH 2.1.2.4.

I have the query cache setup with Fluent NHibernate like this:

```
MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
    .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache()
            .ProviderClass(typeof(NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2.SysCacheProvider)))
```

My criteria looks like this:

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Employee>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Username", username))
    .SetMaxResults(1)
    .SetCacheable(true)
    .UniqueResult<Employee>();
```

However, when I use SQL Profiler I can see the query is still always being executed against the database. No inserts or updates to the Employee table are being made.
Why is it not working?

My Employee mapping class specifies Employee as cachable like this:

```
public sealed class EmployeeDbMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeDbMap()
    {
        ....

        Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}
```

BTW I see there are a number of related questions on Stackoverflow, but none seem to have good answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801239/nhibernate-query-cache-makes-one-request-per-row-to-fetch-entities) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626643/nhibernate-query-cache-not-working-after-update-to-the-database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not caching the Employee entity too, a query will be needed to load it, as the query cache stores the results as ids.

Also, NHibernate cache only works if you do all your work (including queries) inside transactions.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not caching the Employee entity too'? Employee is mapped as cachable. Do you mean that at some point prior Session.Load<Employee>() has to have been called? Is there more I need to do?

Comment: @cbp: @cbp: that's what I meant. If Employee is mapped as cacheable, it should be working. See added comment about transactions too.